# Компоненты Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Есть два компонента

```
    Vue.component('my-temp', {
      template: '<div><span></span></div>'
    });

    Vue.component('my-temp-1', {
      template: '<h1>test</h1>'
    });

    let vm = new Vue({
      el: "#app"
    });


  <div id="app">
    <!--<my-temp>
      <my-temp-1></my-temp-1>
     </my-temp>-->
  </div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы компонент my-temp-1 оказался внутри тега span компонента my-temp. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Vue.component('my-temp', {
      template: '<div><span><my-temp-1></my-temp-1></span></div>'
    });

    Vue.component('my-temp-1', {
      template: '<h1>test</h1>'
    });


Если кому-то понадобится

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Vue.component('my-temp', {
      template: '<div>
 <span>
  <slot></slot>
 </span></div>'
    });

Vue.component('my-temp-1', {
      template: '<h1>test</h1>'
    });

<div id="app">
    <my-temp>
      <my-temp-1/>
     </my-temp>
  </div>
```